# How to insert moment JS time into MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, momentjs

```
//In Node/JS
myDate = moment(data.myTime.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS')).toISOString();
//myDate shows '2014-09-24T04:09:00.000Z'

Insert INTO (dateColumn..) Values(myDate)...
```

This is the error I get after inserting, note column in Mysql is a "datetime" type.

> MySQL Error:: { [Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: '2014-09- 24T04:09:00.000Z' for column '_dateColumn' at row 1]
>       code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE',

Comment: in Mysql, the column is a  "datetime" type.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This result happens because you are using the [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) method and it is not a valid format to insert into your `DATETIME` column. The correct format *probably* is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`(I think it depends on MySQL configuration, but this is the default) as the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) points out.

So you should try using moment's [format()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method like this:

```
myDate =  moment(data.myTime.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

In fact, I don't know what `data.myTime` is, but if its a moment object too, you can change the first `format()` method and remove the second one.

Comment: The line you gave me is giving me an object:{ _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: '9-24-2014',
  _f: undefined,
  _l: undefined,
  _strict: undefined,
  _isUTC: false,
  _pf: 
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [],
     overflow: -2,
     charsLeftOver: 0,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: false },
  _d: Wed Sep 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  _isValid: true }

Comment: @user1529412 well, it should return a string.

Comment: Note that my original data.myTime is an object itself like this: { _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: '9-24-2014',
  _f: undefined,
  _l: undefined,
  _strict: undefined,
  _isUTC: false,
  _pf: 
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [],
     overflow: -2,
     charsLeftOver: 0,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: false },
  _d: Wed Sep 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) }

Comment: @user1529412 so its a moment object too, right? Did you tryied to forma it itself, or you are using a secund format?

Comment: @user1529412 nice, glad to help.

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` should be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Comment: moment will substitue `MM` with the month value. Try this `moment(timeString, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');`

Answer (score 34):

[DontVoteMeDown answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26047884/4263562) is right, except that the minutes `'mm'` and seconds `'ss'` need to be in lowercase, otherwise a wrong value is returned:

```
myDate =  moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Also, you should check the value sent by javascript before to do your SQL query, in PHP:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $myDate);
```

Will return `false` if the date is misformatted.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a function extension to format it into the MySQL DateTime format

```
moment.prototype.toMySqlDateTime = function () {
    return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
};
```

You'll be able to do: `moment().toMySqlDateTime();`

Comment: I find this really convenient to use.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm working with Node.js, Express and MySql and this has worked for me:)

```js
var momentDate=new moment('2018-08-31T20:13:00.000Z');
var readyToInsert=momentDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 4):

To generate mysql format datetime you can use this:

```
var moment = require('moment');
let currentTimestamp = moment().unix();//in seconds
let currentDatetime = moment(currentTimestamp*1000).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");//mysql datetime.
currentTimestamp = moment(currentDatetime).valueOf();//current timestamp in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 4):

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct format. Otherwise you get the months inserted in your minutes, and you also get seconds above 60.

```
myDate =  moment(data.myTime.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:ss')).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
```

Tested in Chrome with Moment.js 2.9.0

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`