# Material-Ui DatePicker change to string

Tags: datepicker, material-ui

Is there a way to make Material-UI DatePicker value to be `String` and not `Date Object`? I just want to have YYYY-MM-DD for the date value. Right now what I'm doing is editing it before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` objects in Javascript have a prototype function to change the date to a string.

```
var date = new Date();
var abc = date.toString();

console.log(abc); // Returns "Thu Feb 16 2017 12:01:19 GMT-0800 (PST)"
```

If you are referring to how to change the date to a particular format prior to sending to to the server, you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
are use a function like
`moment(dateObject, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` after you extract the `dateObject` from the `DatePicker`.

Here is a quick fiddle that shows the moment formatting in action: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fjz56wgg/

Comment: That's what I am actually doing right now. I'm just looking for a way for it to change on the component side not before submitting.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the value to be a string instead of a date object in the component itself? If you look at the source of the `DatePicker` component on github, there are a few functions build into the component that requires the `value` property to be a date object, for example, the `formatDate` function. It would be much easier to massage the value once you retrieve it from the component than do any modifications to that value as a string.

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/DatePicker/DatePicker.js

Comment: `formatDate` function only changes the look of the date object. It will still be date object when you send it to the server. Database requires date data type with YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: I'm guessing you have a mySQL database and need it in that format, correct? You can transform the date object to the correct date format for mySQL by using moment prior to sending it to the server. I don't get why you need to modify the value in the component itself. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047755/how-to-insert-moment-js-time-into-mysql

`formattedValue  =  moment(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: Imagine hundreds of fields of date objects that needs editing. Now imagine editing defining it yourself one by one. You can check if it is a date object BUT imagine if it there are some fields that requires datetime. So you can't really have it all. The only way is to format it on the component itself

Answer (score 0):

This is the best material ui datepicker I have found to date. It allows the user to type and select a date and also displays a string value (which can also be used as the input value). Hope it helps!

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
import Clear from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/clear';
import DateIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/date-range';
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/FontIcon';
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import withHandlers from 'recompose/withHandlers';
import withState from 'recompose/withState';
import moment from 'moment';

const convertDateToYyyyMmDd = (date) => {
  if (!date) return '';
  return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};

const enhance = compose(
  withState('stringValue', 'changeStringValue', props => {
    const { value } = props;
    if (value) return format(props.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    return '';
  }),
  withState('valueOnFocus', 'changeValueOnFocus', ''),
  withHandlers({
    onChangeDatePicker: props => (event, val) => {
      props.input.onChange(
        format(val, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      );
      props.changeStringValue(format(val, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
    },
    onChange: props => (event, val) => props.changeStringValue(val),
    onBlur: props => event => {
      const { value } = event.target;
      if (value != props.valueOnFocus) {
        if (!value) {
          props.input.onChange(null);
          props.changeStringValue('');
        } else {
          const date = new Date(convertDateToYyyyMmDd(value));
          props.input.onChange(date);
          props.changeStringValue(format(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
        }
      }
    },
    onFocus: props => () => props.changeValueOnFocus(props.value),
    clearDate: props => () => {
      props.input.onChange(null),
      props.changeStringValue('');
    }
  }),
);

class MyDatePicker extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    input: PropTypes.object,
    mode: PropTypes.string,
    floatingLabelText: PropTypes.string,
    textFieldStyle: PropTypes.object,
    tree: PropTypes.Object,
    fieldName: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.string | PropTypes.number,
    stringValue: PropTypes.string | PropTypes.number,
    errorText: PropTypes.string,
    disabled: PropTypes.boolean,
    onChangeDatePicker: PropTypes.func,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    clearDate: PropTypes.func,
    onBlur: PropTypes.func,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    value: null,
    stringValue: '',
    errorText: '',
    disabled: false,
  }

  render() {
    const {
      errorText,
      disabled,
      onChangeDatePicker,
      onChange,
      onBlur,
      onFocus,
      clearDate,
      input,
      mode,
      floatingLabelText,
      textFieldStyle } = this.props;

    const stringValue = this.props.stringValue ? this.props.stringValue : input.value ? format(input.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
    const valueDate = input.value ? new Date(input.value ) : {};

    return (
      <div className="P-date-field">
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText}
          type="text"
          value={stringValue || ''}
          errorText={errorText}
          disabled={disabled}
          fullWidth
          onChange={onChange}
          style={textFieldStyle}
          ref="datePicker"
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onFocus={onFocus}
        />
        <FontIcon
          id="iconCalendar"
          className="material-icons"
          title="Open calendar"
          onClick={!disabled ? () => this.datePicker.focus() : null}
        >
          <DateIcon />
        </FontIcon>
        <FontIcon
          style={disabled ? {display: 'none'} : ''}
          id="iconClear"
          className="material-icons"
          title="Clear date"
          onClick={clearDate}
        >
          <Clear />
        </FontIcon>
        <div className="datePicker-hidden">
          <DatePicker
            id="dataPicker"
            name={input.name}
            floatingLabelText={''}
            value={valueDate}
            errorText={errorText}
            disabled={disabled}
            DateTimeFormat={window.Intl.DateTimeFormat}
            locale="de-CH-1996"
            formatDate={v => format(v, 'DD/MM/YYYY')}
            mode={mode}
            autoOk={true}
            fullWidth
            cancelLabel="Cancel"
            onChange={onChangeDatePicker}
            ref={c => (this.datePicker = c)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default enhance(MyDatePicker);
```